# How to respond to a prompt within a shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I'm trying to answer a command prompt for the user within the script.

*Command*

```
ufw enable
```

*Prompt*

```
Command may disrupt existing ssh connections. Proceed with operation (y|n)?
```

*Piece of code that I'm using but its not working properly:*

```
function awk_ufw {
    ufw status | grep Status | awk '{print $2}'
}

.
.
.

    local CHECK_STATUS=$(awk_ufw)
    if [ $CHECK_STATUS == "active" ]
    then
        echo "----------------------------"
        echo "Firewall is already enabled!"
        echo "----------------------------"
    else
        read -p "Before you enable the firewall, please ensure that at least inbound port for your ssh connection is open, otherwise you'll be locked out if ssh is the only way to access the system! [Please type \"understood\" to continue]: " UNDERSTOOD_PROMPT
        if [[ $UNDERSTOOD_PROMPT == "understood" || $UNDERSTOOD_PROMPT == "UNDERSTOOD" ]]
        then
            ufw enable <EOF
            y
            EOF
            if [ $? == "0" ]
            then
                echo "-----------------"
                echo "Firewall enabled!"
                echo "-----------------"
            else
                echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
                echo "Something went wrong during the process, unsure whether firewall was enabled, please recheck manually!"
                echo "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            fi
        else
            echo "------------------------------------------------------"
            echo "Skipping the step since \"Understood\" wasn't entered!"
            echo "------------------------------------------------------"
        fi
    fi
```

Code break on

```
            ufw enable <EOF
            y
            EOF
```

```
Before you enable the firewall, please ensure that at least inbound port for your ssh connection is open, otherwise you'll be locked out if ssh is the only way to access the system! [Please type "understood" to continue]: understood
./script.sh: line 84: EOF: No such file or directory
./script.sh: line 85: y: command not found
./script.sh: line 86: EOF: command not found
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Something went wrong during the process, unsure whether firewall was enabled, please recheck manually!
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Any suggestions how to correct it/improve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It's often easier to do something like `echo y | ufw enable` instead of using here-documents

Comment: To use a here-document, you need a double-`<` instead of a single one. So `<<EOF` instead of `<EOF` (and don't indent the actual `EOF` marker).

Comment: Shellcheck detects this pattern if you provide `<<`; but not otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The end marker in heredocs cannot be indented:

```
cat << MARKER
  content
MARKER
```

works, while:

```
cat << MARKER
  content
  MARKER
```

doesn't.

And heredocs uses two lt symbols: `<< MARKER`. `< thing` is a redirection.

In your case it would be:

```
        if [[ $UNDERSTOOD_PROMPT == "understood" || $UNDERSTOOD_PROMPT == "UNDERSTOOD" ]]
        then
            ufw enable <<EOF
            y
EOF
```

But you might consider piping `echo y |` instead:

```
echo y | ufw enable
```

Which is effectually the same in your case.

FYI awk can do pattern matching, to there is no need to you to pipe `grep | awk`:

```
awk_ufw() {
    ufw status | awk '/Status/ {print $2}'
}
```

Or possible just check the first field:

```
awk_ufw() {
    ufw status | awk '$1 == "Status" {print $2}'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A quick scan of [the man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/ufw.8.html#remote%20management) shows you can avoid the problem all together:

> By default, ufw will prompt when enabling the firewall while running
> under ssh. This can be disabled by using 'ufw --force enable'.

So using:

```
ufw --force enable
```

in your script avoids the issue of having to pass a keypress in.